# How to access environment variables set in a script later in a batch file run from same script?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

My code:

```
file = open("crash_reports_envs.txt")
envVariables=file.read()
print(envVariables)
file.close()

os.environ['linuxwdir'] = (re.search("linuxwdir:(\S+)",envVariables).group(1))
os.environ['invertwdir']= (re.search("wdir:(\S+.*)\\n",envVariables).group(1))
```

I am setting these environment variables in the script and running a batch file `file1` from the same script, I have another `file1` in same folder where the script is. How I can use these variables in that batch file? Right now the batch file does not recognize these variables.

Comment: file1= (os.environ['invertwdir']+'/file1.bat')
p1 = subprocess.Popen(file1, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p1.communicate()
print (p1.returncode)

Comment: Please format you code, and put the code running the `cmd.exe`. .bat file in your post.  It *should* work, how are you trying to access the variables in the `cmd.exe` .bat file?  Are you sure that the variable have a value before you run the file?

Comment: I am using subprocess.Popen

Comment: my file1.bat has below


cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"


pscp.exe -pw "pswd" "invertwdir/file2" uname@execServer:linuxwdir/file2

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code from the script showing how you use `subprocess.Popen` to run the batch file _and_ the code in the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use environment variables in .bat files is to surround them with %, for example %linuxwdir%.  If I understand your `.bat` file correctly, you need something like this (untested):

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY" 
pscp.exe -pw "pswd" "%invertwdir%/file2" uname@execServer:%linuxwdir%/file2
```